# How to use handlebars array passed to template

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, handlebars.js

I have a variable that contains a simple array such as:

```
var terms = ["1 year", "2 years"]
```

And am trying to pass this on to my handlebars template by doing this:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#template').html() );

$('div.container').append(template(terms)).append(template(data));
```

But I don't know how to access the `terms` in my template. I have tried:

```
{{#each terms}}
     {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

I can access the `data` from an ajax call by using something like:

```
 {{#each this}}
     {{column_name}}
{{/each}}
```

But I'm confused about  how to access the variable that I'm appending. By the way, is there a cleaner way to add variables of data to the context? I am brand new to Handlebars and this is the only way I have seen the code set up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more Mustache flavored, but it should solve your problem:

```
<script id="tmp" type="text/x-template">
     <div>
        {{#terms}}
            <p>
                {{.}}
            </p>
        {{/terms}}
    </div>
</script>

var data = {terms: ['1 year', '2 years']};
var template = document.getElementById("tmp").innerHTML;
var templateCompile = Handlebars.compile(template);
var result = templateCompile(data);

console.log(result) // <div><p>1 year</p><p>2 years</p></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMBGC/19/)